# Postgres Join Table Error if First Select is Empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres. I have three tables: **pictures**, **tags** and **picture_tags**.

picture_tags is a join table.

Columns worth mentioning:

```
picture.id
tag.id
picture_tags.picture_id
picture_tags.tag_id
```

I am trying to run the following query to get all tags for picture id 100:

```
SELECT * FROM picture_tags
WHERE picture_id = 100
JOIN tags
ON tags.id = picture_tags.tag_id;
```

In my app there is a chance that a Picture may not have any Tags, thus there will be no picture_tags record to associate the two. When there is no Tags for a Picture, I get the following error:

```
syntax error at or near "JOIN"
```

since my select query returns nothing / is empty. If my select query is empty, is there a way to exit early before trying to join? Trying to make a fail-safe for when the select returns empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.*,PTG.*,TG.*
FROM PICTURE AS P
LEFT JOIN PICTURE_TAGS AS PTG ON P.PICTURE_ID=PTG.PICTURE_ID
LEFT JOIN TAGS AS TG ON PTG.TAG_ID=TG.TAG_ID
WHERE P.PICTURE_ID=100
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge, and how our solution tackles it.

Comment: you are absolutely free to do this